# Converting a file into a dictionary with one key and multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I have a data file that looks like this:

[image]

I want to make the first column into a key and the values that come after the key into values of a dictionary.

This is the code I used but it didn't give me what I wanted.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    ...: 
    ...:     for line in f:
    ...:         items = line.split()
    ...:         key, values = items[0], items[1:]
    ...:         my_dict[int(key)] = values
```

Comment: In what sense is it not what you want?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `my_dict[int(key)] = map(int,values)`

Comment: More generally, please give sample input as actual copyable text rather than a screenshot, and the expected and actual output.

Comment: I suspect it's not working because the keys are not unique. There are a lot of duplicate values in the first column of the data (I'm assuming the first numbers seen in the screenshot are row numbers from the editor, not part of the datafile itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to concatenate additional values from lines with the same key instead of overwriting them, you could use:

```
for line in f:
    items = line.split()
    key, values = int(items[0]), items[1:]
    my_dict.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)
```

Comment: A more elegant concatenation would be: `my_dict.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)` (or you could use a `defaultdict` to make it even simpler).

Comment: Or at least `mydict.get(key, [])`. Abusing `or` that way is usually not necessary in Python.

Comment: @kojiro: blckknght already said that. But defaultdict isn't any simpler (or less simple) than setdefault; what matters is whether you want a regular dict or a defaultdict at the end of the building process.